# In App Purchase status Waiting for Upload

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I have uploaded my application binary and status is "Waiting for Review". I am trying to test the In-App purchase in my application . I have followed the steps but was not able to change the status of the my In App purchase which still says "Waiting for upload". I get this warning on the In App page:

> Note: This In-App Purchase is not currently available for testing in
>   the sandbox environment because you have chosen to host your content
>   with Apple, but have not delivered your content. Upload your content
>   to test this In-App Purchase in sandbox.

How can i resolve this warning ?

**Edit:** GOT IT.

The problem was i had tick the box in the In App purchase saying "Host content using apple" . And i dint upload any content to host . Because i just need a approval from apple to convert my lite version to paid version.

Comment: Do you want to host your IAP at Apple? This requires iOS 6!

Comment: yes i am trying to do that. I am already using iOS 6.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have created a container in iTunes connect, you can click a button "ready for upload". That means your itunes connect is now expecting you to create an archive of your product and submit for review using Xcode.

To get from "Waiting for binary" to "waiting for review" is to submit your binary archive from Xcode.

before click a button "ready for upload", You have to enable the  In_App products.After that you can't enable your In_App products.